# How to calculate CRC

Tags: crc

I am having problems understanding how to calculate CRC because of the long math involved. I understand things like XOR, but all the examples use really long numbers. What is the breakdown of the steps and a really simple example?

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways of approaching "understanding how to calculate CRC".

- How can I calculate some particular CRC? The bit-serial approach is the easiest to understand. See [Wikipedia: CRC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/cyclic_redundancy_check) and the first quarter of [Wikipedia: computation of CRC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computation_of_CRC), and example code in JavaScript and C at [CRC parameters](http://www.zorc.breitbandkatze.de/crc.html).
- Why exactly is a properly-designed CRC guaranteed to detect a burst error with length one less than the length of the CRC? How do I design new CRC polynomials that are deliberately incompatible with previous standards? See [Wikipedia: Mathematics of CRC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematics_of_CRC)
- How can I make my software CRC run faster, but still remain compatible with some particular CRC? What's up with all these tables of mysterious constants I see in "optimized" CRC code? See the rest of [Wikipedia: computation of CRC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computation_of_CRC) and [The CRC Pitstop](http://www.ross.net/crc/).